# Disable Siri fully via terminal Ventura

Tags: macos, terminal, launchd, siri, ventura

What is the latest way to disable Siri via Terminal on Ventura? I'm ok to do SIP disable and re-enable later.

I have tried

```
sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Siri.agent.plist
sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.siriactionsd.plist
sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.siriknowledged.plist
sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.sirittsd.plist
sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.assistantd.plist

sudo rm -rf /System/Library/CoreServices/Siri.app

sudo defaults write /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Siri.plist Disabled -bool true
sudo defaults write com.apple.Siri StatusMenuVisible -bool false
sudo defaults write com.apple.Siri UserHasDeclinedEnable -bool true
sudo defaults write com.apple.assistant.support 'Assistant Enabled' 0

defaults write com.apple.Siri StatusMenuVisible -bool false
defaults write com.apple.Siri UserHasDeclinedEnable -bool true
defaults write com.apple.assistant.support 'Assistant Enabled' 0


sudo killall -HUP cfprefsd
sudo killall SystemUIServer
sudo reboot now
```

But dont think these work, i get errors about read only

Maybe there is a script that disables useless telemetry services on Ventura?

Comment: You can't change the OS. Just turn it off in System Settings. Apple isn't listening. If you really want, you can use an app like Little Snitch, to stop any outward connections and give you more innocent things to worry about.

Comment: Everything can be changed in OS its just knowing how to, most of the time terminal is there for.

Comment: No, the OS is on a read-only, cryptographically sealed volume. If you do manage to alter it, it won't boot. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web